# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'reshape' (type Reshape)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am working on image captioning model using satellite images. I have a .json file through which I am training the model for generating captions. Below is my code-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, add, Concatenate, Reshape, concatenate, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16, ResNet50, DenseNet201
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from textwrap import wrap
import json

image_path = '/home/ml/Image_Caption_Generator/sydney/sydney'

'''data = pd.read_csv("/home/ml/Aishwary/new/new_dataset/captions.txt")
print(data.head())
'''
#with open("/Users/aishwaryshree/Desktop/r.json", "r") as json_file:
#    captions_data = json.load(json_file)

# Create a DataFrame from the loaded JSON data
#data = pd.DataFrame(captions_data)
def readImage(path,img_size=224):
    img = load_img(path,color_mode='rgb',target_size=(img_size,img_size))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.
    
    return img

def display_images(temp_df):
    temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)
    plt.figure(figsize = (20 , 20))
    n = 0
    for i in range(15):
        n+=1
        plt.subplot(5 , 5, n)
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.7, wspace = 0.3)
        image = readImage(f"/home/ml/Image_Caption_Generator/sydney/sydney/{temp_df.image[i]}")
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.title("\n".join(wrap(temp_df.caption[i], 20)))
        plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
def text_preprocessing(data):
    # Assuming "images" contains a list of image objects, and each image object has a "sentences" key
    for image in data["images"]:
        sentences = image["sentences"]
        for sentence in sentences:
            sentence["raw"] = sentence["raw"].lower()
            sentence["raw"] = ' '.join(sentence["raw"].split())
            sentence["raw"] = 'startseq ' + sentence["raw"] + ' endseq'
    return data


with open("/home/ml/Image_Caption_Generator/sydney.json", "r") as json_file:
    captions_data = json.load(json_file)

# Preprocess the captions data
processed_data = text_preprocessing(captions_data)

# Create a DataFrame from the processed JSON data if needed
data = pd.DataFrame(processed_data["images"])

#data = text_preprocessing(data)

#captions = data['raw'].tolist()
#captions[:10]
captions = []
for image in data["sentences"]:
    for sentence in image:
        raw_caption = sentence["raw"]
        # Preprocess the caption as needed
        raw_caption = raw_caption.lower()
        raw_caption = ' '.join(raw_caption.split())
        raw_caption = 'startseq ' + raw_caption + ' endseq'
        captions.append(raw_caption)




tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(captions)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
max_length = max(len(caption.split()) for caption in captions)

#images = data['image'].unique().tolist()
#nimages = len(images)

#split_index = round(0.85*nimages)
#train_images = images[:split_index]
#val_images = images[split_index:]
images = set()
for sentences in data["sentences"]:
    for sentence in sentences:
        img_id = sentence["imgid"]
        images.add(img_id)

images = list(images)
nimages = len(images)

split_index = round(0.85 * nimages)
train_images = images[:split_index]
val_images = images[split_index:]


train = data[data['imgid'].isin(train_images)]
test = data[data['imgid'].isin(val_images)]

train.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([captions[1]])[0]

model = DenseNet201(weights = 'home/ml/Aishwary/densenet201_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
fe = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
img_size = 224
features = {}
for image_id in tqdm(range(1, 10)):  # Assuming image IDs range from 1 to 2100
    image_filename = str(image_id) + ".tif"  # Assuming the image files have '.tif' extension
    img = load_img(os.path.join(image_path, image_filename), target_size=(img_size, img_size))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img / 255.
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    feature = fe.predict(img, verbose=0)
    features[image_id] = feature


class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
        
    def __init__(self, df, X_col, y_col, batch_size, directory, tokenizer, vocab_size, max_length, features, shuffle=True):
        
        self.df = df.copy()
        self.X_col = X_col
        self.y_col = y_col
            
        self.directory = directory
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.features = features
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.n = len(self.df)
            
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.shuffle:
            self.df = self.df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n // self.batch_size
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch = self.df.iloc[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size, :]
        X1, X2, y = self.__get_data(batch)
        return (X1, X2), y
        
    def __get_data(self, batch):
    X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
    
    for _, row in batch.iterrows():
        image_id = row[self.X_col]
        adjusted_image_id = image_id - 1
        if adjusted_image_id in self.features:
            feature = self.features[adjusted_image_id]
            captions = row[self.y_col]
            
            for caption in captions:
                if isinstance(caption, str):  # Check if caption is a string
                    seq = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([caption])[0]
                    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
                        in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
                        in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=self.max_length)[0]
                        out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=self.vocab_size)[0]
                        X1.append(feature)
                        X2.append(in_seq)
                        y.append(out_seq)
                    
    X1, X2, y = np.array(X1), np.array(X2), np.array(y)
    X1 = X1.reshape(-1, 1920)  # Reshape X1 to match the input shape
    return X1, X2, y
input1 = Input(shape=(1920,))
input2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))

img_features = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input1)
#img_features_reshaped = Reshape((1, 256), input_shape=(256,))(img_features)

sentence_features = Embedding(vocab_size, 256, mask_zero=False)(input2)
sentence_features = Reshape((256, ))(sentence_features) 
#merged = concatenate([img_features_reshaped,sentence_features],axis=1)
sentence_features = LSTM(256)(sentence_features)
x = concatenate([img_features, sentence_features])
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
#x = add([x, img_features])
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)

caption_model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=output)
caption_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')


caption_model.summary()

train_generator = CustomDataGenerator(df=train,X_col='imgid',y_col='sentences',batch_size=64,directory=image_path,
                                      tokenizer=tokenizer,vocab_size=vocab_size,max_length=max_length,features=features)

validation_generator = CustomDataGenerator(df=test,X_col='imgid',y_col='sentences',batch_size=64,directory=image_path,
                                      tokenizer=tokenizer,vocab_size=vocab_size,max_length=max_length,features=features)
model_name = "model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_name,
                            monitor="val_loss",
                            mode="min",
                            save_best_only = True,
                            verbose=1)

earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta = 0, patience = 5, verbose = 1, restore_best_weights=True)

learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                                            patience=3, 
                                            verbose=1, 
                                            factor=0.2, 
                                            min_lr=0.00000001)

history = caption_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        callbacks=[checkpoint,earlystopping,learning_rate_reduction])


plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

def idx_to_word(integer,tokenizer):
    
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index==integer:
            return word
    return None

def predict_caption(model, image, tokenizer, max_length, features):
    
    feature = features[image]
    in_text = "startseq"
    for i in range(max_length):
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)[0]

        y_pred = model.predict([feature,sequence])
        y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred)
        
        word = idx_to_word(y_pred, tokenizer)
        
        if word is None:
            break
            
        in_text+= " " + word
        
        if word == 'endseq':
            break
            
    return in_text 

samples = test.sample(15)
samples.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

for index,record in samples.iterrows():

    img = load_img(os.path.join(image_path,record['image']),target_size=(224,224))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255.
    
    caption = predict_caption(caption_model, record['image'], tokenizer, max_length, features)
    samples.loc[index,'caption'] = caption

display_images(samples)
```

When I am trying to run this code, I am getting the following error -

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'reshape' (type Reshape).
total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [256], output_shape = [256, 27]
Call arguments received by layer 'reshape' (type Reshape):
inputs = tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 27, 256), dtype=float32)
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I am very new to Machine Learning

I tried adding the Reshape layer for input but it is not working

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback? So we can see where the error originates.

Comment: sure I will provide the code in the question part itself

Comment: That's too much code to sensibly debug for a single answer. Could dyou try and create an [mcve]? Also, there's still not the full traceback, nor do we know where the error originates in the code.